# How do you query a pymongo db with a list of object_ids?

Tags: python, database, pymongo

I'm trying to query a MongoDB but for a list of `_ids`.

For example:

```
db.test.find(ObjectId(['4ecc05e55dd98a436ddcc47c',4ecc05e55dd98a436adfc47c', ....] ))
```

Comment: you need to search by list of `object_Id`?

Comment: yes, ideally want to store all IDs in a list and pass that list through for db.test.find ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator, e.g.

```
db.test.find({'_id': {'$in': [ObjectId("4ecc05e55dd98a436ddcc47c"), ObjectId("4ecc05e55dd98a436adfc47c")]}})
```

This works in both Mongo shell and pymongo.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your list:

```
list_of_ids = [ObjectId("4ecc05e55dd98a436ddcc47c"),ObjectId("4ecc05e55dd98a436adfc47c")]
```

and run `db.test.find({'_id': {'$in': list(list_of_ids)}}`.